# How can I check more than two values with <condition>?<if true>:<if false>?

Tags: c#

How can I check more than one case and assign based on that?

I have:

```
str[1] = (Setting.DBL(this.fieldTxt3.Tag.ToString()) == 1000 ? Setting.IP2 : Setting.IP4);
str[3] = (Setting.DBL(this.fieldTxt3.Tag.ToString()) == 1000 ? "TBSS2" : "TBSS4");
```

But I want something more like:

```
str[1] = (Setting.DBL(this.fieldTxt3.Tag.ToString()) >= 3000 ? Setting.IP5 : Setting.IP4 : <additional options>);   
str[3] = (Setting.DBL(this.fieldTxt3.Tag.ToString()) == 1000 ? "TBSS2" : "TBSS4" : <additional options>);
```

Comment: What does that even mean? What values other than "true"and "false" are you trying to handle?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "adding more values"? If the condition is true you get one value, otherwise you get the other. Under what conditions would the third and fourth values get returned? Do you want a `switch` block instead?

Comment: I'm guessing that what you really want is a `switch` statement, not the ternary operator.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you want a bunch of `if` statements, but if you really to use the ternary operator, you can nest statements, e.g.: `comparison? value_if_true : (comparison_2 ? value_2_if_true : (comparison_3 ? value_3_if_true : value_3_if_false)))`

Comment: i want to add more TBSS to my code...   In any way

Answer (score 8):

The feature you want is called "match expressions" and it has not been added to C# yet.  It likely will be in a future version. See the [roslyn github forum](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/fab7134296816fc80019c60b0f5bef7400cf23ea/docs/features/patterns.md) for details.

The syntax is proposed to be something like:

```
 double area = someShape switch (
    case Line line: 0,
    case Rectangle r: r.Width * r.Height,
    case Circle c: Math.PI * c.Radius * c.Radius,
    case *: throw new ApplicationException()
)
```

Where we are saying here "switch on someShape; if it is a line, its area is zero..." and so on.

Until that happens, use `if` statements.

Comment: To be fair, in your example you could also factor this out to a function which switches in a similar way with a switch that returns the value to be set (Though that loss of locality may not be worth it). In OP's case, it looks like that would be multiple functions or a tuple return, and I think that's far too ugly.